# continuing xml parsing if tag not found in python using minidom

Tags: python

---

### Sample XML Document

```
<Authors>
    <Author>
        <LastName>def</LastName>
        <age>20</age>
    </Author>
    <Author>
        <ForeName>ghi</ForeName>
        <age>22</age>
    </Author>
    <Author>
        <ForeName>mno</ForeName>
        <LastName>pqr</LastName>
        <age>23</age>
    </Author>
</Authors>
```

---

### Sample output

```
Author:
FirstName :  -
LastName :  def

Author:
FirstName :  ghi
LastName : - 

Author:
FirstName :  mno
LastName :  pqr
```

---

### Sample Code

```
import xml.dom.minidom
# use the parse() function to load and parse an XML file
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse("sampleinput.xml");
auth = doc.getElementsByTagName('Author')
for a in auth:
    print("Author:")
    try:
        print("FirstName : ",a.getElementsByTagName("ForeName")[0].firstChild.data)
    except:
        print("FirstName : - ")
    try:
        print("LastName : ",a.getElementsByTagName("LastName")[0].firstChild.data)
    except:
        print("LastName : - ")
```

i want to insert an '-' symbol if corresponding tag is not found. is there any other reliable way to do that rather than try and except?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is! So lets see what happens when you actually run `a.getElementsByTagName` if it does not contain your target element.

```
for a in auth:
    print(a.getElementsByTagName("ForeName"))

>>
[]
[<DOM Element: ForeName at 0x163a17226d0>]
[<DOM Element: ForeName at 0x163a1722898>]
```

Right, now we know that if you try to get an element it does not have, it returns an empty list and is also aligned to the documentation:

> A NodeList represents a sequence of nodes. These objects are used in
>   two ways in the DOM Core recommendation: an Element object provides
>   one as its list of child nodes, and the getElementsByTagName() and
>   getElementsByTagNameNS() methods of Node return objects with this
>   interface to represent query results.

Now instead of doing the `try` and `except` loop, you can explicitly check if the element is present before printing your data with:

```
for a in auth:
    if a.getElementsByTagName("ForeName"):
        print("FirstName : ",a.getElementsByTagName("ForeName")[0].firstChild.data)
    else:
        print("FirstName : - ")

>>
FirstName : - 
FirstName :  ghi
FirstName :  mno
```

Here the `if` block checks to see if it is not empty and followed by a print. Ff the `NodeList` is empty, it prints the dash.